# recreating a sentence, recreated sentence is missing all commas

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that should be able to compress a file into a list of words and list of positions to recreate the original file. It should also be able to take a compressed file and recreate the full text, including punctuation and capitalisation, of the original file.

So far I have this:

```
file = open("task3paragraph.txt", "w")
file.write ("Two little dicky birds sitting on a wall, one named Peter, one 
named Paul. Fly away Peter, fly away Paul, come back Peter, come back 
Paul.Into the gardens the little birds go, looking for worms that hide down 
low. Peter can’t catch one, neither can Paul, back home Peter, back home 
Paul!")
file.close()


file = open("task3paragraph.txt", "r")
paragraph = file.read()
para  = paragraph.split()
positions = [para.index(x)+1 for x in para]
para2 = str(para)
pos = str(positions)
file.close()


file = open("task3lists.txt", "w")
file.write(para2)
file.write("\n")
file.write(pos)
file.close()


file = open("task3lists.txt", "r")
words = file.readlines()
sentence = words[0].replace("
[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").replace(",","")
file.close()


file = open("task3recreated", "w")
file.write(sentence)
file.close()
```

And it works perfectly except towards the end when I ran it, because the recreated sentence had no commas:

> Two little dicky birds sitting on a wall one named Peter one named Paul. Fly away Peter fly away Paul come back Peter come back Paul.Into the gardens the little birds go looking for worms that hide down low. Peter can’t catch one neither can Paul back home Peter back home Paul!

It was missing all the commas that the original sentence had:

> Two little dicky birds sitting on a wall, one named Peter, one named Paul. Fly away Peter, fly away Paul, come back Peter, come back Paul.Into the gardens the little birds go, looking for worms that hide down low. Peter can’t catch one, neither can Paul, back home Peter, back home Paul!

I want my recreated sentence to have the same number of commas as my original. How do I fix it?

- Also, I removed the .replace(",","") and that made it worse because it gave me too many commas:

  > Two, little, dicky, birds, sitting, on, a, wall,, one, named, Peter,, one, named, Paul., Fly, away, Peter,, fly, away, Paul,, come, back, Peter,, come, back, Paul.Into, the, gardens, the, little, birds, go,, looking, for, worms, that, hide, down, low., Peter, can’t, catch, one,, neither, can, Paul,, back, home, Peter,, back, home, Paul!

Comment: Well, you have `replace(",","")` so you are actively looking for commas and replacing them with empty strings instead. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: @roganjosh I tried that and got a comma after every word, sometimes two commas after every word

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that you're storing the _string representations_ of the list in `para2 = str(para)` etc. Instead of having a list of items, you have a string that looks like a list, and the (visual) commas that separated items in the list have become unwanted, real commas in that string. There's a few ways to approach this, either by thinking of a different way to store the raw data, or cleaning up after this issue, which is less useful I think. From the assignment, I think you're supposed to store the data as individual lines in the file, not a whole string, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: re.finditer(pattern, string[, flags])       
Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Comment: You first need to decide how you want to store punctuation in your list. Should `Paul!`, `Paul,` and `Paul` be treated as different words? That is probably the easiest solution. Or you could store the punctuation as if they are separate words e.g. `[... 'one', 'named', 'Peter', ',', 'one' ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace:

```
sentence = words[0].replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").replace(",","")
```

with:

```
sentence = words[0].replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("',","").replace("'", "")
```

Instead of replacing all commas with empty strings, you should only replace the commas that are preceded by a quotation mark.